# Good to append a view inside a view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I over complicated things at first and could not figure out how to create a list within a list using backbone.js. I finally got it, by simply creating a list item view for all of the players in my app. Then created a view for all of the teams inside my app.

I "glued" or "appended" them together by creating an app view that put them together, there is an each statement for both, before the two views were appended to the app view root, I appended the player list item view into the team view. Let me show you.

**Here is my render method inside the app view:** *I am just not sure if this is a bad idea or not, I am thinking there are much better ways, but this is the only method I have had success with. It really makes sense to me, I can run events on each view without a problem*

```
render: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.teams.each(function(team) {
        var teamView = new TeamView({ model: team });
        var teamHtml = teamView.render().el;

        var teamPlayers = this.players.where({team_id: team.get('id')})          
        _.each(teamPlayers, function(player) {
            var playerView = new PlayerView({ model: player });
            var playerHtml = playerView.render().el;

            $(teamHtml).append(playerHtml);

        }, this);

        this.$el.append(teamHtml);

    }, this);

    return this;
},
```

I asked about this and was told it would be better to create sub-views, well I am pretty sure this is a sub-view structure? Are there any holes to this method, if so I would like an explanation why this method is bad and how I can improve it. Last but not least I do care about clean maintainable code but what matters most is that I have `teams` wrap its respected `players` with an HTML result like below.

```
<div>
  <ul class="lakers">
      <li>Kobe</li>
      <li>Pau</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="spurs">
      <li>Tony</li>
      <li>Tim</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Again id like some constructive criticism, mainly **PROS** & **CONS** with connecting the two views like that. Just needed to ask before I move on I want to make sure I am not getting into bad habits or creating problems in my code when I start expanding it, I am sure you understand that.

Answer (score 0):

> I asked about this and was told it would be better to create sub-views, well I am pretty sure this is a sub-view structure?

Yes you knew it, and `TeamView` is sub-view. However it's a "zombie view". Does it do anything itself? A view should be responsible of rendering itself, including appending its direct sub-views, but **without knowing how to render its sub-views**, i.e., you should pass the `players` collection to the `TeamView` and move the following logic into `TeamView`:

```
    var teamPlayers = this.players.where({team_id: team.get('id')})          
    _.each(teamPlayers, function(player) {
        var playerView = new PlayerView({ model: player });
        var playerHtml = playerView.render().el;

        $(teamHtml).append(playerHtml);

    }, this);
```

Comment: Ohh, you see I did try that but got confused on how to write `var teamPlayers = this.players.where({team_id: team.get('id')}) ` well I still am, the `team.get` would be undefined. `teamPlayers` only works when its inside an each teams loop.

Comment: Also confused how I would loop teams, there are 4 teams that have about 5-6 players. Maybe I am being dumb and missing something simple but this is getting to me lol.

Comment: I know it's hard to see what `teamPlayers` is doing but on the players model there is an attribute `team_id` and that needs to match its associated team. `team.get('id')` may return 1, 2, 3, or 4 (4 teams) then it will add players with `team_id` 1-4 to its respected team. That is the whole point of having to view to wrap the players and associate them.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry I think `players` is the sub-collection of `teams`, right? You have already passed `team` to `TeamView`; to make it work you just need to pass the related players. You can either pass the entire `collections` and let `TeamView` do the filter, or filter outside and pass the `teamPlayers` to `TeamView`. It should be easy, otherwise I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry You said the `team.get` would be undefined in `TeamView`? Since it's passed as model, you should use `this.model.get` instead, you knew that, right?

Comment: Yeah I did, but what's more important is that the team view needs to be looped (similar to `players`) for however amount of teams there are. I have two collections right teams has 4 models, players has idk about 50 models that has a team_id they are associated to the team.